# Webkit android вывод элементов

Tags: java, android, webkit

Если ли какая нибудь возможность в webkit выводить определенные элементы/блоки со страницы сайта, работоспособные. Например, есть мобильная версия сайта Яндекс  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли в мобильном приложении посредством webkit вывести работоспособный блок поиска, чтобы изображался пользователю только он? Причем чтобы он оставался функционировать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если задача конкретно в поисковой строке яндекса, то можно попробовать выводить не yandex.ru, а ya.ru.

Comment: К сожалению нет